# why do the values are added to database when numbers are inserted in the student name?

Tags: php

this is my coding
i think there is something wrong in the validation part.
can plz anyone help me?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("school", $con);

$student_fname=$_POST['student_fname'];
$student_lname=$_POST['student_lname'];
$student_ic=$_POST['student_ic'];
$student_age=$_POST['student_age'];
$student_race=$_POST['student_race'];
$student_gender=$_POST['student_gender'];
$student_phone=$_POST['student_phone'];
$student_class=$_POST['student_class'];
$student_email=$_POST['student_email'];
$student_add=$_POST['student_add'];
$student_city=$_POST['student_city'];
$student_state=$_POST['student_state'];
$student_postcode=$_POST['student_postcode'];
$student_id=$_POST['student_id'];
$student_pswd=$_POST['student_pswd'];
$student_cpswd=$_POST['student_cpswd'];


if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $student_fname)) === false) {

echo "<script language='Javascript'>alert('Student First Name must only contain letters!');
                    location.href='rstudent.php'</script>";
}

if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $student_lname)) === false) {


echo "<script language='Javascript'>alert('Student Last Name must only contain letters!');
                    location.href='rstudent.php'</script>";
}

if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $student_city)) === false) {

echo "<script language='Javascript'>alert('City must only contain letters!');
                    location.href='rstudent.php'</script>";
}   
if($student_pswd==$student_cpswd)
    {
$sql="INSERT INTO student (student_fname, student_lname, student_ic, student_age,
student_race, student_gender, student_phone, student_class, student_email, student_add,
student_city, student_state, student_postcode, student_id, student_pswd, student_cpswd)
VALUES
('$_POST[student_fname]', '$_POST[student_lname]', '$_POST[student_ic]', '$_POST[student_age]',
 '$_POST[student_race]', '$_POST[student_gender]', '$_POST[student_phone]', 
 '$_POST[student_class]', '$_POST[student_email]', '$_POST[student_add]', '$_POST[student_city]',
  '$_POST[student_state]', '$_POST[student_postcode]', '$_POST[student_id]', 
 '$_POST[student_pswd]', '$_POST[student_cpswd]')";
    }
else 
    {
        echo "<script language='Javascript'>alert('Password must match!');
                    location.href='rstudent.php'</script>";
    }




 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 echo "<script language='Javascript'>alert('The Student Profile Has been Successfully 
 Registered!!!');
 location.href='srecords.php'</script>";
 mysql_close($con)
 ?>
```

why is my validation for only letters, when inserted numbers it still add in the database?

Comment: Where is your part of database insertion? I think you need to set a flag variable, what is false, and if any error in it, then set true.
Before insert, check this variable. You now just alerts the user.

Comment: Are you asking "Why do the values pass validation when numbers are included in the student name?"?

Comment: I understand what you think should happen `location.href='rstudent.php'` if validation failed reload the page right? but its too late by then, all the php has been executed at the serverend before the browser even sees the js

Answer (score 1):

It's because the script continues it's normal execution when one of the validation statements fails.

Meaning, you are just echo-ing some javascript but this won't do anything to the normal php flow. The javascript will be outputed after php has done it's processing and inserted the values in the database.

In the IF statements you must take another action that will prevent the script in reaching the DB insert part.

Simplest solution for your case:

```
if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $student_fname)) === false) 
{
    echo "<script language='Javascript'>alert('Student First Name must only contain letters!');
                        location.href='rstudent.php'</script>";
    exit;
}
```

Notice the "exit" in the IF statement. This will cause the script to end execution when the validation fails, preventing the insert.

A better solution would be to have something like:

```
$form_validation = true;

if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $student_fname)) === false) 
{
    echo "<script language='Javascript'>alert('Student First Name must only contain letters!');
                        location.href='rstudent.php'</script>";
    $form_validation = false;
}

if($form_validation == false)
{
    echo 'Form validation failed';
    exit;
}
else
{
    /* insert the values in the DB */
}
```

The solution above would allow you to check all statements before ending execution.

It would also be best to redirect using `header('Location: rstudent.php'); exit;` but this would require you to save the message in the `$_SESSION` and then check them.

So the best solution would be to save all error messages in an array, check the array if it's empty at the end of validation and if it's not save the error messages in the user `$_SESSION`, redirect the page using `header('Location: rstudent.php''); exit;` and in that page check for errors, display them to the user and clear them so that they won't show again :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in this code remembers when a value was identified as invalid. You're generating some javascript, but not telling PHP to do anything else. Remember, by the time the javascript is rendered in the browser, the PHP server has already finished processing the PHP.

Create a variable such as `$passes_validation=true;`, Then everywhere you have a validation step, set `$passes_validation=false;` when the validation fails. Something like this:

```
$passes_validation=true;
if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $student_fname)) === false) {

    echo "<script language='Javascript'>alert('Student First Name must only contain letters!');
                    location.href='rstudent.php'</script>";
    $passes_validation=false;
}
```

Then, only execute the sql if `$passes_validation==true`. Something like this:

```
if($passes_validation){
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```